# Yii2: how to use Asset Bundle for scripts

Tags: yii2

I have read the docs, but can't make out how to do that for example I have a small script in file `index.php` in view folder `medicine-issue-entry` like:

```
<?php
$js = 'function refresh() {
     $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine_request_entry"});
     setTimeout(refresh, 60000); // restart the function every 5 seconds
 }
 refresh();';
 $this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_READY);
?>
```

Where I can put this code in a separate file and how to include that in the relevant file.
A detailed process will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Ok I am using the basic template.
In `AppAsset.php` I have included like

```
public $js = [

        'js/autorefresh.js'
    ];
```

and created a folder `js` in `web folder` and created a new file autorefresh.js with the following code:

```
function refresh() {
         $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine_request_entry"});
         setTimeout(refresh, 60000); // restart the function every 5 seconds
     }
     refresh();
```

and in my `index.php` I have added the line

```
namespace app\assets;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

But the same is not working, am I still missing something? As when I include the code in the file with `registerJs` it is working fine.

**Note:** on viewing the page source the file is correctly published and clicking on the link it show the script, but the code is not working.

Comment: Since your code seems to be using jQuery, you do have `yii\web\JqueryAsset` in the `$depends`-section of your `AppAssets`-bundle, right? Otherwise it is including the javascript file but it doesn't have a jQuery to call. Check out your browsers' error console for javascript errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the **Basic** Template for Yii2

Add your `autorefresh.js` script to the `/web/js/` directory

```
function refresh() {
    $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine_request_entry"});
    setTimeout(refresh, 60000); // restart the function every 5 seconds
}
refresh();
```

Add your script to the `$js` array inside AppAsset class located in `/assets/AppAsset.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
         'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/autorefresh.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Make sure that your AssetBundle is registered.

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

or

```
\app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
```

> NOTE: Your don't set the namespace of the index.php file.

Comment: Hi user764429 - I have updated my question based on suggestion, but it looks like I am still missing something as I couldn't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: Hi user764429 - if I am using use assets\AppAsset I am getting the error - `Class 'assets\AppAsset' not found`. If I am using `use app\assets\AppAsset` then I am not getting any error, but the script is not working

Comment: What he meant is that you don't use the `namespace` statement for a view, however his suggestion is indeed missing the "app" part. You can either do `use app\assets\AppAsset; AppAsset::register($this);` or `\app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);`  - which I personally prefer for 1-time usage in a file.